# Linear phase Notch filter / Band reject filter implementation in C++

Tags: filters

I'd like to implement a digital notch filter, which has linear phase, in C++ or C#.
Example : a notch filter that removes 400hz frequency on a .wav file (16 bit, 44.1 Khz, stereo).
I'm a bit lost with many examples, I don't achieve to implement them.
Maybe some of you has a working example?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See equation 19-8 on this page: http://www.dspguide.com/ch19/3.htm

Comment: @PaulR thanks, but I already have some good theory books... The problem is that I don't know achieve to implement them with a practical code in C++... Would you have a working example in C++? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The page I linked to gives you the formula for the coefficients for a simple notch filter - all you have to do is calculate the coefficients from the formula and then apply that. If you don't know how to implement a filter once you have the coefficients then I'll post some code later.

Comment: @PaulR I understand the maths, the coefficient computation, but I don't know how to make a C++ code running on WAV files with such a filter...

Comment: OK - I've put some example C/C++ code in an answer below which shows how to implement a simple recursive filter using coefficients a0, a1, a2, b1, b2 - this can be used for any 2nd order IIR filter, but if you use coefficients from the link above you'll get a notch filter.

Comment: "removes 400hz frequency" can you quantify this a bit (ie BW, attn) as it will affect the implementation

Answer (score 5):

You can implement a simple recursive filter to process blocks of samples like this:

```
void filter(const int *x, int *y, int n)
{
    static float x_2 = 0.0f;                    // delayed x, y samples
    static float x_1 = 0.0f;
    static float y_2 = 0.0f;
    static float y_1 = 0.0f;

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        y[i] = a0 * x[i] + a1 * x_1 + a2 * x_2  // IIR difference equation
                         + b1 * y_1 + b2 * y_2;
        x_2 = x_1;                              // shift delayed x, y samples
        x_1 = x[i];
        y_2 = y_1;
        y_1 = y[i];
    }
}
```

Notch filter coefficients a0, a1, a2, b1, b2 can be calculated using eq 19-8 on this page: http://dspguide.com/ch19/3.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot PaulR, I will try to paste this in my code!
Is it possible to include the computation of a0, a1, a2, b1, b2 directly in the code, then the only parameter would be f (frequency) ? (with some math C++ functions) ?

Last question : do you think this method can be used in order to do super-precise notch filter like this one (super high Q value) (example using a VST) https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/83031018/forum/4g-NotchFilteredFabFilterProQVST.jpg

Comment: The coefficients would typically be calculated once, when the centre frequency is defined or changed, and then they are just passed into the filtering function as parameters. I don't know what you mean by "super-precise" - a filter is just something that matches its specification - what aspect of the filter specification are you particularly concerned about ?

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm looking for a notch filter with very high Q, very narrow band (see screenshot in previous comment). Do you think I need high order filtering for such a narrow band? Is your code cited here adapted for that purpose ?
2nd thing : I need linear phase filtering. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think you need linear phase ? For higher Q you can just increase the order of the filter, but note that ringing artefacts become an increasing problem if you want very high Q.

Comment: I need linear phase because of further application of my algorithm (too long to explain in this small comment ;) )...
How to increase the order of the filter ?

Comment: If it really has to be linear phase then that means a much longer FIR filter, so it's back to square one.

Comment: Ok PaulR, so what do I have to do?
I have updated the question in order to add this linear phase question...

Comment: What kind of filter was the one that you gave in your answer ? Was it a IIR or FIR ?

Comment: The filter above is IIR and so not linear phase - you'll need to design an FIR filter with a large number of terms if you want a high Q notch and linear phase.

Comment: Thanks PaulR. Do you have a reference for that or an implementation sample code? Even if this is very intersting, I don't want to re-invent the wheel, so, if it already exists, I would be glad to use it.

Comment: Assuming this is for a fixed frequency you will need a filter design program to generate the coefficients. It's going to be tedious though - if you really do need high Q and linear phase then the filter may well have hundreds of coefficients and the design process could be slow and painful. I don't know how big a filter MATLAB can design, but you might try it, otherwise you may need a specific filter design program. At this point I would ask on DSP.SE as your problem has become quite challenging now.

Comment: Yes, you can hit the `flag` link below the question above and ask a moderator to migrate it.

Comment: One way to implement a linear-phase FIR filter with variable frequency and Q is to use the Goertzel algorithm. Its advantage is that the computation time does not depend on Q, so you can set it as high as you want (if the inevitable ringing artifacts are not a problem). The equivalent of "windowing in the frequency domain" can be used to achieve a flat passband. You (or anyone else) can contact me at the address given in my profile if you need source code.

Comment: `y_2` is referenced but not declared or assigned.

Comment: @Clifford: thanks - I *think* it's fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

If you usually use Matlab for analysis the files, you might want to consider using Simulink and then just generate the code of the filter. Especially if this is something you run in real time (ie inputting audio and processing it on the fly).

Another approach is using the coefficients as was suggested above.Once you have those you can use the following formula:

```
output[i] = A[0] * in[2] + A[1] * in[1] + A[2] * in[0] - B[1] * out[1] - B[2] * out[0];
```

Where A/B are you coefficients, in[0,1,2] are 3 points of you original file and out [0,1,2] is the filtered one. Of-course for the first few points there are no values of out[0,1] and you should erase them after filtration.

By running this formula and shifting both in and out at each point you will result in your filtered signal.

See [this thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/297133) for further explanation

Comment: You are right! Fixed it...

Answer (score 2):

I found a proper C-Code example on this page

http://www.dsprelated.com/showcode/173.php

It helped me a lot, so maybe some of you are also interested...

Comment: What is "proper C-Code"?  Or are you somehow suggesting that doing it in C++ is improper!?